# Nvidia to ATI card change over issue

Tags: drivers, ati

I have added an ATI card to my machine and want to use it instead of my onboard Nvidia card. I tried to boot into Ubuntu but the screen goes blank, fail safe grahics won't work either. I have sudo apt-get purge nvidia* and yet, I'm still not able to boot in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to look at your BIOS settings to set the primary video device.

http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Onboard/Integrated-Video-On-Your-Computer

Comment: You should always disable one card before using the other in the BIOS.  Otherwise, there could be times where your system just can't figure out which one it should be using.